# Oracle Apex Theme Javascript Minification

Tags: javascript, css, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Currently I am working on a APEX 5 application with the Universal Theme. I am a bit frustrated due to the fact that it uses so many different small Javascript files, this leads to a lot of HTTP requests. It seems that good practice is to combine the different files into one minified file. I have tried the "Concatenated Files" function but it seems that this only applies to Javascript or CSS that the developer makes themselves. This is something I cannot find a lot of documentation about from Oracle or other people.

Is there a way to manually bundle and concatenate the different Javascript and CSS files that a APEX 5 theme uses? Is there a way to use the Concatenated Files function for files the theme uses?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to raise on https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=55447

Comment: Are these multiple requests and small file actually causing you problems?